# How to fill the gap by using IDW(inverse distance weighting method) in R?

Tags: r, inverse-distance-weighted, filling, gap

I'm beginner of R. I'm trying to fill the gap using idw, but I still had no idea about this.

The data in used is below:

[image]

The names sequence of columns are date/SO2/CO/O3/NO2/PM10/Lat/Lon. As you see, the gap values is existed in NO2 column. So I totally want to fill up this gap using idw through all location at the same date. It means like below picture num2.

[image]

Above picture has same date and different locations. So I want to use it to fill the gap by using idw.

I hope that you can understand what I'm trying to say (I'm Korean).

## EDIT : Show my terrible code below

```
library(ggplot2)
library(rgdal)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(gstat)
library(rgdal)
library(raster)
library(rgeos)
library(scales)
library(GISTools)
library(rgdal)
library(sp)
air_test <- read.csv("D:/aircondition/air_1Qu.csv", header = T)
str(air_test)
air_order <- air_test[order(air_test$측정일시),]
air_order <- air_order[,4:11]
a.fac <- as.factor(air_order$측정일시)
a.df <- data.frame(a.fac,air_order)
a.df <- a.df[,-2]
str(a.df)
names(a.df)[1] <-c("DATE") 
a.df$ID <- as.integer(a.df$DATE)
str(a.df)
a.loc <- a.df[,7:9]
colSums(is.na(a.PM10))
str(a.df)



for (i in 1 : length(unique(a.df$ID))) {
  idw <- a.df[a.df$ID==i,]
    for (j in 2:6) {
    idw.air <- na.omit(idw)
    idw.air <- data.frame(idw.air[j], idw.air[,7:9])
    coordinates(idw.air) <- ~Lon + Lat
    proj4string(idw.air) <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
    idw.air_t <- spTransform(idw.air, CRS("+init=epsg:32651"))
    idw.final <- idw(formula = names(idw)[j] ~ 1, locations = idw.air_t,
                                      newdata = int.layer, idp = 2)
    idw.output.df <- as.data.frame(idw.final) %>% as.tibble()
    idw.output.df
  }
}
```

As you see, my codes are very mash. I really hope that the gap in my data is filled and I want to save the whole data which is fixed.
So, I totally want to be professional about R. Could you recommend something like books about R?

## ERROR MESSAGES when I ran the code

```
Error in predict.gstat(g, newdata = newdata, block = block, nsim = nsim,  : 
  too many spatial dimensions: 226
In addition: Warning message: 
In predict.gstat(g, newdata = newdata, block = block, nsim = nsim,  :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

Comment: Have you looked at any of the packages that have functions do IDW? e.g. `gstat`?

Comment: Hi! and thank you for your comments. I had used a lots of packages, and I'm totally beginner of R. So I don't know exactly the packages which I used.  I used this packages below to run the code. library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(gstat)
library(rgdal)
library(raster)
library(rgeos)
library(scales)

Comment: Have you read any tutorial on fitting IDW models? Can you edit your question to show the code you have used and where you have got stuck?

Comment: I re-uploaded my codes, it's really terrible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to use `idw` to predict at some locations.

Use only these two packages:

```
> library(sp)
> library(gstat)
```

Make a test data set of 20 points with 20 N values that are the measurement we are interested in:

```
> d = data.frame(x=runif(20), y=runif(20), N=rnorm(20))
> coordinates(d)=~x+y
```

Let's set 3 of our measurements to `NA` because these are missing - we want to fill these locations in:

```
> d$N[c(5,6,7)]=NA
```

Now run `idw` with our valid data as `locations` and our prediction locations as `newdata`. Note how we use `valid` as a true/false index to subset our data:

```
> valid = !is.na(d$N)
> predictions = idw(N~1, 
       locations=d[valid,,drop=FALSE],
       newdata=d[!valid,,drop=FALSE])
```

Giving:

```
> predictions
             coordinates  var1.pred var1.var
5 (0.876017, 0.07675017)  0.3292105       NA
6 (0.3606106, 0.3929375) -0.8818549       NA
7 (0.8988331, 0.8903288)  0.1999656       NA
```

Note the prediction variance is `NA` because the `idw` method has no uncertainty measure. You will get different answers because I've used random numbers.

To put those prediction values back into the original data frame:

```
> d$N[!valid] = predictions$var1.pred
```

To get this to work on your data you will still have to convert the projection, but you only have to do this once - I really don't understand why you have a doubly-nested loop in your code. One call to `idw` will predict at any number of `newdata` locations given a set of valid `location` data with coordinates and measurements.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. The reason why I've used a doubly-nested loop is the number of values in data. In the data, the number of values are 5. So, I tried to run the code by having doubly-nested loop code. Above the code you said, what if I have lots of values, how can I write down the code to interpolate the missing values?

Comment: Thanks for your comments again. I have a question about choosing your advice on my problem. could you give me followings?

Comment: I've given you the code to interpolate the missing values. Do you want to repeat this for five *columns* as responses?